# Filter by Value rather than by label in an XSSFPivotTable with Apache POI and Java

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am trying to add an AutoFilter to a pivot table column which filters the data by value instead of by caption. This is my code on how I am trying to do it:

```
pivotTable2.addColumnLabel(DataConsolidateFunction.SUM, 29);
        pivotTable2.addRowLabel(29);
        pivotTable2.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getPivotFields().getPivotFieldArray(29).setDataField(true);
```

-- Skipping making table lines of code --

```
org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTPivotFilters filters =
                        org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTPivotFilters.Factory.newInstance();
                org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTPivotFilter filter = filters.addNewFilter();
                filter.setId(0);
                filter.setFld(29);
                filter.setType(org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.STPivotFilterType.VALUE_LESS_THAN);
                filter.setStringValue1("0");
                CTFilterColumn myCol = filter.addNewAutoFilter().addNewFilterColumn();
                CTCustomFilters myFilter2= myCol.addNewCustomFilters();
                CTCustomFilter custFilt = myFilter2.addNewCustomFilter();

            custFilt.setOperator(STFilterOperator.LESS_THAN);
            custFilt.setVal("0");
           // filter.addNewAutoFilter().addNewFilterColumn().addNewCustomFilters().addNewCustomFilter().setVal("0");
            filter.getAutoFilter().setRef("A1");
            filter.getAutoFilter().getFilterColumnArray(0).setColId(0);

            //set filters to pivot table definition
            pivotTable2.getCTPivotTableDefinition().setFilters(filters);
```

However, whenever I run this code, the data filter does not appear for the pivot table and instead prints the pivot table as normal. If I try CAPTION_LESS_THAN, it autofilters for the label filter rather than the value filter. It may have to do with adding a data filter, but I am not sure where to add it. Can you please help me out on this.

Comment: Have you ever ask yourself why your multiple questions about pivot tables not get answers? Well it is not clear what exactly you are trying to achieve because of the lack of [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @AxelRichter Look at this new example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63891316/apache-poi-filter-a-pivot-table-using-the-value-filters-instead-of-the-label-fi