# Apache Poi- Filter a Pivot Table Using the Value Filters instead of the Label Filters using Java

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

To whom it may concern,

I am currently stuck on trying to add a filter to a pivot table in java using excel which filters by the sum of the columns instead of by the labels. However, when I try and filter it by value, I instead get a pivot table with no filtering done at all. This is what the current table looks like, even when I try and do value filtering:

[image]

And this is my code (this example is actually reproducible):

```
package com.tutorialspoint.spring;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.ss.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTAutoFilter;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTCustomFilter;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTCustomFilters;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTDataField;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTDataFields;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTFilter;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTFilterColumn;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTFilters;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTPivotField;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.STFilterOperator;

import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

class CreatePivotTableFilter {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  try (Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); 
       FileOutputStream fileout = new FileOutputStream("MyExcelV2.xlsx") ) {

   DataFormat format = workbook.createDataFormat();
   CellStyle dateStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
   dateStyle.setDataFormat(format.getFormat("M\\/d\\/yy"));
   Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();
   String[] headers = new String[]{"Column1", "Column2", "Date", "IntVal", "Count"};
   Row row = sheet.createRow(0);
   Cell cell;
   for (int c = 0; c < headers.length; c++) {
    cell = row.createCell(c); cell.setCellValue(headers[c]);
   }
   Object[][] data = new Object[][]{
    new Object[]{"A", "B1", new GregorianCalendar(2019, 0, 1),  2d},
    new Object[]{"A", "B2", new GregorianCalendar(2019, 0, 1),  4d},
    new Object[]{"B", "B1", new GregorianCalendar(2019, 0, 2),  1d},
    new Object[]{"B", "B2", new GregorianCalendar(2019, 0, 2),  7d},
    new Object[]{"A", "C1", new GregorianCalendar(2019, 0, 1),  5d},
    new Object[]{"A", "C2", new GregorianCalendar(2019, 0, 1),  5d},
    new Object[]{"B", "C1", new GregorianCalendar(2019, 0, 2), 2d},
    new Object[]{"B", "C2", new GregorianCalendar(2019, 0, 2),  8d}
   };
   for (int r = 0; r < data.length; r++) {
    row = sheet.createRow(r+1);
    Object[] rowData = data[r];
    for (int c = 0; c < rowData.length; c++) {
     cell = row.createCell(c);
     if (rowData[c] instanceof String) {
      cell.setCellValue((String)rowData[c]);
     } else if (rowData[c] instanceof GregorianCalendar) {
      cell.setCellValue((GregorianCalendar)rowData[c]);
      cell.setCellStyle(dateStyle);
     } else if (rowData[c] instanceof Double) {
      cell.setCellValue((Double)rowData[c]);
     }
     else if (rowData[c] instanceof Integer)
         cell.setCellValue((Integer) rowData[c]);
    }
   }

   XSSFPivotTable pivotTable = ((XSSFSheet)sheet).createPivotTable(
    new AreaReference("A1:D9", 
    SpreadsheetVersion.EXCEL2007), 
    new CellReference("F4"));
   pivotTable.addRowLabel(0);
   pivotTable.addRowLabel(1);
   pivotTable.addColLabel(2);
   pivotTable.addColumnLabel(DataConsolidateFunction.SUM, 3);
   pivotTable.addColumnLabel(DataConsolidateFunction.AVERAGE, 3);
   pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().setOutline(true);
   pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().setOutlineData(false);
   for (CTPivotField pf: pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getPivotFields().getPivotFieldList())
   {
    System.out.println("FOO");

    pf.setOutline(true);
    pf.setDefaultSubtotal(true);
   }
   org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTPivotFilters filters =
    org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTPivotFilters.Factory.newInstance();
    org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTPivotFilter field = filters.addNewFilter();
   field.setId(0);
   field.setFld(1);
   field.setType(org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.STPivotFilterType.VALUE_LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL);
   field.setStringValue1("3");
   CTFilterColumn myCol = field.addNewAutoFilter().addNewFilterColumn();
   CTCustomFilters myFilter2= myCol.addNewCustomFilters();
   CTCustomFilter custFilt = myFilter2.addNewCustomFilter();
   custFilt.setOperator(STFilterOperator.LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL);
   custFilt.setVal("3");
     field.getAutoFilter().setRef("A1");
   field.getAutoFilter().getFilterColumnArray(0).setColId(0);
   System.out.println(sheet.getLastRowNum());
   System.out.println(pivotTable.getColLabelColumns());
   System.out.println(pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getDataFields().toString());
   pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().setFilters(filters);
   workbook.write(fileout);
  }

 }
}
```

Because this project is done with Java using Spring boot, these dependencies need to be added to the pom.xml file, if not done already:

```
        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.2</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/ooxml-schemas -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

I know the code is really close to accessing the value filters, I think I forgot what I need to do to access them. Please help me!

Comment: FYI for the MyExcel.xlsx line of code, put the path to where you want to store the file!

Comment: For me it is not clear what you are trying to achieve. How would you do it using `Excel`'s GUI? Your code properly creates a pivot table. Now what exactly would you do usinf `Excel`'s GUI to reach your goal?

Comment: So, if I want to access the value filters using the excel's GUI, I would click on the proper column and scroll to value filters. I would then click on what I want the sum to be. I.E. Show values where SUM is less than 5. I want to know if there is a possible way to do it programatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that your code sets `StringValue1` for `CTPivotFilter`. But it should set `IMeasureFld`.

The internal measure field `IMeasureFld` sets the data field on which the filter shall filter. In this case `0` is the first data filed having a data consolidate function -> Sum. `IMeasureFld` `1` would be the second data filed having a data consolidate function -> Average.

Following code provides a minimal working example. The code is commented where it is not self describing.

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.ss.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTCustomFilter;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTCustomFilters;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTDataField;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTFilter;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTFilterColumn;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.STFilterOperator;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTPivotFilters;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTPivotFilter;

import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

class CreatePivotTableFilter {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  try (Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); 
       FileOutputStream fileout = new FileOutputStream("./MyExcelV2.xlsx") ) {

   DataFormat format = workbook.createDataFormat();
   CellStyle dateStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
   dateStyle.setDataFormat(format.getFormat("M\\/d\\/yy"));
   Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();
   String[] headers = new String[]{"Column1", "Column2", "Date", "IntVal", "Count"};
   Row row = sheet.createRow(0);
   Cell cell;
   for (int c = 0; c < headers.length; c++) {
    cell = row.createCell(c); cell.setCellValue(headers[c]);
   }
   Object[][] data = new Object[][]{
    new Object[]{"A", "B1", new GregorianCalendar(2019, 0, 1),  2d},
    new Object[]{"A", "B2", new GregorianCalendar(2019, 0, 1),  4d},
    new Object[]{"B", "B1", new GregorianCalendar(2019, 0, 2),  1d},
    new Object[]{"B", "B2", new GregorianCalendar(2019, 0, 2),  7d},
    new Object[]{"A", "C1", new GregorianCalendar(2019, 0, 1),  5d},
    new Object[]{"A", "C2", new GregorianCalendar(2019, 0, 1),  5d},
    new Object[]{"B", "C1", new GregorianCalendar(2019, 0, 2),  2d},
    new Object[]{"B", "C2", new GregorianCalendar(2019, 0, 2),  8d}
   };
   for (int r = 0; r < data.length; r++) {
    row = sheet.createRow(r+1);
    Object[] rowData = data[r];
    for (int c = 0; c < rowData.length; c++) {
     cell = row.createCell(c);
     if (rowData[c] instanceof String) {
      cell.setCellValue((String)rowData[c]);
     } else if (rowData[c] instanceof GregorianCalendar) {
      cell.setCellValue((GregorianCalendar)rowData[c]);
      cell.setCellStyle(dateStyle);
     } else if (rowData[c] instanceof Double) {
      cell.setCellValue((Double)rowData[c]);
     }
     else if (rowData[c] instanceof Integer)
         cell.setCellValue((Integer) rowData[c]);
    }
   }

   XSSFPivotTable pivotTable = ((XSSFSheet)sheet).createPivotTable(
    new AreaReference("A1:D9", 
    SpreadsheetVersion.EXCEL2007), 
    new CellReference("F4"));
   pivotTable.addRowLabel(0);
   pivotTable.addRowLabel(1);
   pivotTable.addColLabel(2);
   pivotTable.addColumnLabel(DataConsolidateFunction.SUM, 3);
   pivotTable.addColumnLabel(DataConsolidateFunction.AVERAGE, 3);

   //create filters
   CTPivotFilters filters = CTPivotFilters.Factory.newInstance();

   //set custom value filter
   int filtersCount = 0; // to count filters
   CTPivotFilter filter = filters.addNewFilter();
   filter.setId(0); // filter needs Id
   filter.setFld(1); // filter on column B level
   filter.setType(org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.STPivotFilterType.VALUE_LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL);
   filter.setIMeasureFld(0); //internal measure field is 0 (first data field) = Sum; 1 would be Average
   CTFilterColumn filterColumn = filter.addNewAutoFilter().addNewFilterColumn();
   filterColumn.setColId(0); // filterColumn need colId
   CTCustomFilters customFilters= filterColumn.addNewCustomFilters();
   CTCustomFilter customFilter = customFilters.addNewCustomFilter();
   customFilter.setOperator(STFilterOperator.LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL);
   customFilter.setVal("3");

   filtersCount++;
   filters.setCount(filtersCount); // set filters count

   pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().setFilters(filters);

   workbook.write(fileout);
  }

 }
}
```

It produces:

[image]